# Reading INI file from PHP which contains Semicolons

Tags: php, parsing, ini

I have to read config files in PHP which contain entries with semicolons, e.g.

```
[section]
key=value;othervalue
```

I notices that `parse_ini_file()` removes all semicolons and what follows, even when set to `INI_SCANNER_RAW`.

The INI files come from legacy systems and I can't change the format. I only have to read them.

What's the best tool to use when I have to preserve the entries with semicolons?

Comment: Quote the entry in the ini file: `key="value;othervalue"`... otherwise a `;` introduces a comment

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the INI files. They come from an environment where only semicolons at the start of a line designate a comment. A lot of valid etries in that environment contain semicolons within values.

Comment: @MarkBaker That comment should be the accepted answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ini files, the `;` is the comment symbol.
So it's actually a good idea to not use it for something else.

However, you can use this slightly modified functions from the solutions found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#78815) :

```
<?php
//Credits to goulven.ch AT gmail DOT com 
function parse_ini ( $filepath )
{
    $ini = file( $filepath );
    if ( count( $ini ) == 0 ) { return array(); }
    $sections = array();
    $values = array();
    $globals = array();

    $i = 0;
    foreach( $ini as $line ){
        $line = trim( $line );
        // Comments
        if ( $line == '' || $line{0} == ';' ) { continue; }
        // Sections
        if ( $line{0} == '[' )
        {
            $sections[] = substr( $line, 1, -1 );
            $i++;
            continue;
        }
        // Key-value pair
        list( $key, $value ) = explode( '=', $line, 2 );        
        $key = trim( $key );
        $value = trim( $value );

        if (strpos($value, ";") !== false)
            $value = explode(";", $value);

        if ( $i == 0 ) {
            // Array values
            if ( substr( $line, -1, 2 ) == '[]' ) {
                $globals[ $key ][] = $value;
            } else {
                $globals[ $key ] = $value;
            }
        } else {
            // Array values
            if ( substr( $line, -1, 2 ) == '[]' ) {
                $values[ $i - 1 ][ $key ][] = $value;
            } else {
                $values[ $i - 1 ][ $key ] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    for( $j=0; $j<$i; $j++ ) {
        $result[ $sections[ $j ] ] = $values[ $j ];
    }
    return $result + $globals;
}
```

You can see examples of usage following the link.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend reading the file into an array first, convert the semicolons to pipes |, then spit that out to a temporary file and use parse_ini_file() with that new temporary file.

Like so...

```
$string = file_get_contents('your_file');

$newstring = str_replace(";","|",$string);

$tempfile = 'your_temp_filename';

file_put_contents($tempfile, $newstring);

$arrIni = parse_ini_file($tempfile);
```

Then after that you could always replace the pipes with semicolons as you enumerate your new INI based array.